# How to "Trim" an Audio File in Java, C# or PHP (For Browser)

Tags: c#, java, php, audio, trim

I'm trying to create a web application which requires this feature:

Suppose I have a .mp3 file, I want to select/upload this file, and then, make a new file of it from 0:15 to 0:30 (example), and then save as new .mp3/.wav.

As it's supposed to go on web, would be preferrable in PHP, but as I highly doubt it's possible, Java(Applets) or C#(ASP.NET) are acceptable and highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is with [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).  There is a [PHP extension for it](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/), but I've generally found that it is easiest to just call it with [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:15 -t 15 -i yourfile.mp3 -acodec copy outputfile.mp3`

More info here:  http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it in Java, you could use the AudioSamples class from [JAudio](http://jmir.sourceforge.net/jAudio.html).

```
// read the file into an AudioSamples object
AudioSamples as = new AudioSamples(new File("originalFile.mp3"),"",false);

// get the audio from 15 to 30 seconds
double[][] samples = as.getSamplesChannelSegregated(15.0, 30.0);

// discard the rest of the samples
as.setSamples(samples);

// write the samples to a .wav file
as.saveAudio(new File("newAudioFileName.wav"), true, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, false);
```

Comment: where we get AudioSamples class?

Comment: @dB is there a way to do exactly this in Javascript / Cordova?