# Trim an mp3 file?

Tags: android, c, mp3, trim

I want to trim a music file(mp3).I want to do it in c,c++ or Java.So what are the libraries that I can use to do this.I want it for my android application.So help me on how it can be integrated with my application.It is good if someone has some answers regarding this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are already several similar but not identical questions around:

[How to "Trim" an Audio File in Java, C# or PHP (For Browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495319/how-to-trim-an-audio-file-in-java-c-sharp-or-php-for-browser/6500444#6500444)

[java mp3/audio editing/trimming library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278612/java-mp3-audio-editing-trimming-library)

[Crop MP3 to first 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890/crop-mp3-to-first-30-seconds)

and also ways to utilize them:

[ffmpeg for a android (using tutorial: "ffmpeg and Android.mk")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645041/ffmpeg-for-a-android-using-tutorial-ffmpeg-and-android-mk)